# How to query custom defined join table

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three models `user`, `tab`, `subscription`. User can subscribe to many tabs and tab can have many subscribers. 
`user --* subscription *-- tab`

Diagram from navicat

[image]

```
sequelize.define('subscription', {})

Tab.belongsToMany(User, { through: Subscription })
User.belongsToMany(Tab, { through: Subscription })
```

How do I get all subscribers for specific tab or all tabs which specific user subscribes to?
I could do that in two queries but it have to be possible in one.

I have tried every possible combination of `where`, `include`, `through` which I would rather not share here. Every time I try to get access to subscription from any side I get `subscription (subscriptions) is not associated to user`.

I am trying to get something like this to work.

```
  await Tab.findAll({
    where: { name: ctx.params.tabname },
    include: [{
      model: Subscription,
      through: {
        where: { userUsername: ctx.params.username }
      }
    }]
  })
```

Comment: Please provide input and expected output, also, provide the relations between the tables.

Comment: So, given a tab, you want to list all of the other tabs that users who are subscribed to your original tab are also subscribed to?

Comment: @rotten Tab is identified by name so if I query tab by name I want to know all its subscribers. Or from the other side, user is identified by username so if I query user by username I want to know all tabs to which is he subscribing

Comment: @sagi Relations between tables are included in my question (code, diagram, second sentence, `user --* subscription *-- tab`) and for the actual data I don't think they are relevant to problem I am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with belongsToMany is that is creates link directly to the destination entity. So to get all users for a specific tab you would have to do

```
Tab.findAll({
 include: [{
    model: User
  }]
});
```

That works when you don't really want to get any data from the subscription entity.

In a case you want to select any data from the subscription entity you need to slightly modify your relations.

```
Tab.hasMany(Subscription);
Subscription.belongsTo(Tab);

User.hasMany(Subscription);
Subscription.belongsTo(User);
```

This will create one to many relation from tab to subscription and add also binding backwards from subscription to tab. The same thing for user.

Then you can query for all subscriptions (with user info) of a specific tab or for all subscriptions (with tab info) for a specific user like following:

```
Tab.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Subscription,
    include: [{
      model: User
    }]
  }]
});

User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Subscription,
    include: [{
      model: Tab
    }]
  }]
});
```

I hope that helps!